# I can't add a new Row to an inline crud table once i get live data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, crud, updates

I am trying to create an inline create and edit function on a table in angular, when i click on 'add', a new row with empty input fields is supposed to be created. works well on mock data but wont create on real data.

```
<table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5" class="bg-slate-400 py-2 ">Commodity and Offtaker Price Informations</th>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">OID</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">UOM</th>
          <th>
            <button
                     type="button"
                     title="Add Commodity"
                     class="btn bg-green-400 text-white hover:bg-green-800 cursor-pointer"
                     (click)="addRow()"
                     >
                      <i class="pi pi-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </th>
        </tr>
 <table>
```

```
  addRow(){
    this.ICommodity.unshift({
      offtakerPriceOID: + 1,
      commodityDescription: '',
      unitPrice: 0,
      unitOfMeasure: ''
    })
    this.itemSelected = this.commodity[+1];
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is with this line:
this.ICommodity.unshift({
You are trying to unshift an object with hardcoded values into the array. Instead, you should use a variable to store the new values entered in the input fields.